# Getting file information from a partial view in an html helper

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core-2.0, partial-views

We're currently working on migrating our website to .net core from .net mvc 5 and in the process trying to implement a new idea for how to use service workers with our site.

Basically, depending on the route of the request, the body and layout will either return fully rendered, or will return with strings in places where partials would normally have been rendered. If the service worker encounters any of these strings on the returned request, it will replace the string with a corresponding partial it had already cached client side, and if it does not have the string it will send a request to the server for that partial alone.

What we need is some method of cache-busting via the strings we include referring to the partials. Ideally, we'd have the string be versioned based on the last time the partial's .cshtml file was modified (or a hash of the partial). Something similar is often done using html helpers for cache busting static files and images.

The problem is that I'm having trouble getting the last write time of the partial files using a static html helper extension. It works well for static resources in the wwwroot folder by simply getting the file's path and then using `File.GetLastWriteTime()` but it's not clear to me that getting the last write time of a .cshtml partial file can be done the same way.

How could I write an html helper extension that will insert a string based on the last write time of a partial view file, given the name of the partial view?

Comment: Sigh. Don't do this. You can cache partials server-side if you just want to speed up the view parsing, but you're trying to basically create an entire framework here from scratch that does not exist. It *almost* sounds like Blazor, but of course, that's a *far* more sophisticated system. What you're trying to do is non-standard, not universally support, 100% dependent on JavaScript, not accessible, will cause problems with SEO, etc. The list goes on and on and on. In the eternal words of Monty Python's the Holy Grail: run away! run away!

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but we're looking to do this in a limited capacity with a handful of predetermined partials that are part of our app shell. I'm unclear on how this is any less accessible, less SEO friendly, or more JavaScript dependent than PRPL with service workers to begin with. If the service worker isn't present, pages will be served entirely as normal, if the service worker is present, it'll intercept the request and use special routes to assemble the shell from partials.